# Calling a C-Function which takes a structure as argument

Tags: c, ada

I'm stuck on this problem that I thought was simple. I have a structure definition and a function that takes an instance of this structure. How can I call this function in Ada? This is an example code:

defines.h :

```c
typedef struct cartesian_t
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} cartesian_t;

void debug_cartesian(struct cartesian_t t);
```

defines.c

```c
void debug_cartesian(struct cartesian_t t)
{
    printf("%f, %f, %f\n", t.x, t.y, t.z);
}
```

main.adb

```
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
    type Cartesian_Record_Type is record
        X : C_Float;
        Y : C_Float;
        Z : C_Float;
    end record
    with
        Convention => C;
        
    procedure Debug_Cartesian(Cart : in Cartesian_Record_Type)
    with
        Import => True,
        Convention => C,
        External_Name => "debug_cartesian";


    T : Cartesian_Record_Type := (
        X => 5.0,
        Y => 1.0,
        Z => -1.0
    );
begin
    Debug_Cartesian(T);
end Main_Union;
```

The output is not what I expect. It should be "5.0, 1.0, -1.0" but something is clearly wrong in memory because I get random values. Like if is putting the data not where C expect them to be.

Comment: For me, it looks like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an implementation advice in [RM B.3](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-B-3.html) to always pass records by reference. GNAT, at least, follows this advice.

To circumvent this, you have two options:

1. Pass the struct by reference in C:

```
 void debug_cartesian(struct cartesian_t *t);
```

or

2. Pass the record by copy in Ada:

```ada
    end record
    with
       Convention => C_Pass_By_Copy;
```